# When scrolling, the text stays behind the background and is not visible.How do I make the text stay fixed when scrolling?

Tags: html, css, css-position

[image]

The "Hikayen Gülümsemen" text is when scrolling, the text stays behind the background and is not visible.
[image]

```css
<style>
    .carousel-item {
        height: 70rem;
        background-color: black;
        position: relative;
        color: black;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    .containerx {
       margin-left: -121px !important;
        margin-top: 400px !important;
       position:fixed;
       z-index:-2;
      
       
    }
    a:hover{
        text-decoration:none !important;
        color:black !important;
    }
   /* a:hover {
        text-decoration:none !important;
    }*/
    a{
        text-decoration:none !important;
    }
    .v-light .dsn-slider .wrapper {
        background-color: #090909;
    }
    a{
        color:white !important;
    }

    body {
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.69) !important;
        font-weight: 500 !important;
        font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    }
    .main-root{
        background-color:black;
    }
    h3{
        font-weight:700;
        font-size:35px;
        line-height:1.2;
    }
    @@media(min-width:1200px) {
        .container {
            max-width: 1140px;
        }
    }
    
</style>
```

```html
<div class="dsn-root-slider" id="dsn-hero-parallax-img" style="background-color:black;">
    <div class="slide-inner">

        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="slide-content">
                <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
                    <!-- Indicators -->
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    </ol>

                    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image:url(Content/assets/Images/bg/pianoDentalClinic_slide1-1.jpg)">

                            <div class="containerx">
                                <div class="title-text-header">
                                    <div class="title-text-header-inner" style="font-weight:500; color:white;">
                                        <a href="#" class="effect-ajax sloganBg" data-dsn-ajax="slider" style="color:white !important;">
                                            @("Hikayen".ToGecerliDileCevir()) @("Gülümsemen".ToGecerliDileCevir())
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="link-custom">
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("Ekle", "Randevu", new { area = "Kayit" })" class="image-zoom " data-dsn="parallax" style="background-color: transparent; border: 1px solid rgba(112, 112, 112, 0.5);"
                                       data-dsn-ajax="slider">
                                        <span>@("RANDEVU İÇİN TIKLAYINIZ".ToGecerliDileCevir()).</span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="carousel-item item" style="background-image:url(Content/assets/Images/bg/pianoDentalClinic_slide2.jpg)">
                            <div class="containerx">
                                <div class="title-text-header">
                                    <div class="title-text-header-inner">
                                        <a href="#" class="effect-ajax sloganBg" data-dsn-ajax="slider" style="color:white !important;">
                                            @("Hikayen".ToGecerliDileCevir()) @("Gülümsemen".ToGecerliDileCevir())
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="link-custom">
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("Ekle", "Randevu", new { area = "Kayit" })" class="image-zoom " data-dsn="parallax" style="background-color: transparent; border: 1px solid rgba(112, 112, 112, 0.5);"
                                       data-dsn-ajax="slider">
                                        <span>@("RANDEVU İÇİN TIKLAYINIZ".ToGecerliDileCevir()).</span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    </div>

                    <!-- Left and right controls -->
                    <div class="slider-arrow-left">
                        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slider-arrow-right">
                        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                        </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="dsn-slider-content"></div>
```

i tried so hard please can you help me?
When the scroll is made or the transform is changed, the text should remain fixed, but a part of it does not appear. With Position fixed, the entire text is visible without scrolling when the page is fixed, but not when scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough information here for me to be sure how to fix it, but you could try using a z-index to manipulate the natural stacking order.

```
 .containerx {
       margin-left: -121px !important;
       margin-top: 400px !important;
       position:fixed;
       z-index: 1;
    }
```

Comment: I tried this before but it didn't work. I actually just added a carousel to the page. Since there is a text in the carousel-item, a part of the direct text does not appear when the trasform is changed. let me add some more content

Comment: gotcha, thanks for the added content, I'll see if I can help.

Comment: when <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" > carousel or dsn-slider-root class  add style Transform:translate(10%); or transform:translate(5%)  text appeared but The image shifts to the right as the percentage increases.

Answer (score -1):

when dsn-root-slider transform changed  text not showing

[image]

Comment: Is this a comment or a solution? If it's additional info about your problem, please delete it and add the information into your question via an edit. Answers are for content that solves the problem posed int he question.